# Fail to upload image on server via php

Tags: php

So I have this code in php that takes the result of a form:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/";
    //$path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );

    is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] ) or error( 'not an HTTP upload' ); 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path ) )
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ) . " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file -->" . $path;
    }


    } ?>
```

The problem I have is that the code go through `is_uploaded_file` but fails when executing `move_uploaded_file`

This code is code that I've find on many php forum and tutorials.

Anyone has any idea why it doesn't upload on my server.

EDIT:

Here's the full .php file with the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Montréal Accessible</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/grid.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9wqmeX_YlaRLZYrnNDOkHcXvlXa9cATo&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/home.js"></script>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/";
        //$path = "uploads/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );

        is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] ) or error( 'not an HTTP upload' ); 

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path ) )
        {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ) . " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file -->" . $path;
        }

        $myvars = '';
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $upImgResponse = curl_exec( $ch );*/
    } ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            loginForm = document.forms[0];
            loginForm.onsubmit=function()
            {
                var name = prompt ("Enter your name","")

                if( loginForm[0].value == '' )
                {
                    alert('Please enter a username');
                    return false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    loginForm.action='../Symfony/web/app.php/login/' + name + '/' + ...;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headerBar">
            <div id="homeLogoColumn">
                <div id="homeLogo">Montréal Accessible</div>
            </div>
            <div id="searchBarColumn">
                <div id="searchBar" class="input-append">
                  <input id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
                  <a id="searchButton" class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="anchorsColumn">
                        <a class="lastAnchor" href="#">À propos</a>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <a href="#">Aide</a>
                        <!--<form name="input" action="" method="post">
                        <a href="#">Connexion</a><input type="submit" value="Connect">
                        </form> -->

            </div>
        </div>


        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
        <tr>
        <td width="246">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
        <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile">
        </td>
        <td width="80"><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        <div id="mainContent">
                <div id="paramsAndResultsColumn">
                    <div id="paramsAndResultsTabs">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#paramsTab"><span>Critères</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#resultsTab"><span>Résultats</span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <div id="paramsTab"></div>
                      <div id="resultsTab"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mapCanvasColumn">
                    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

The error being displayed is the "Sorry, there was a problem uploading...." meaning it goes through the else...

Comment: is $path writable? and are you owner?

Comment: Yes I'm both owner and it is writable.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Fails how (what messages can you see)? 2. What is the `enctype` of the form that is submitting the file?

Comment: Check your `PHP.ini` in case it's not accepting files over 10MB. Many servers have 10MB as the default max size. Even though you have `name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000"`set, that won't bypass it. Check that out as well, it could be part of the problem. It happened to me "once".

Comment: Can you place the `is_uploaded_file` into an if statement and check?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you don't have an `action` for the form. Example `<form action="./upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` unless you left that out in your codes.

Comment: @Fred Not necessary. Omitting the action will cause the page to post back to itself.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary since they are in the same file

Comment: @Ander2 I tried with the if with the same result. The condition is_uploaded_file is successfull

Comment: @ColinMorelli thanks. I tested his script and it worked fine on my server so it's probably a path issue, permissions or his php.ini - I tested it with a 5kb file and it works.

Comment: @nevero By my experience having users upload images on my server, noticed that, if some use an iPhone iPod, etc. the default name of the uploaded image is called `image.jpg`, so you might want to incorporate a renaming function to it. I use a server timestamp along with the uploader's original filename. Food for thought ;-)

Comment: @Fred it would be interesting to see if changing `$path` to other dir solves the problem.

Comment: @Fred thanks that actually a very good idea !!

Comment: @nevero you're welcome. Glad we all could help.

Comment: @Ander2 well, if it works for him at this point (I'm assuming he's a "he"), I won't test further. ;-) cheers

Comment: @nevero to add to my renaming suggestion. If many people upload an image and the name is `image.jpg`, it will constantly get overwritten then you'll end up with people contacting you to say "hey... where's my file/upload?" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help... the problem was a permission problem. I set the permission on the folder with chmod 755 instead of chmod 777

Comment: By default, least on my server, all folders are set to 755. When things don't work, that's when you can chmod to 777 for worse case scenarios. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `
     0)
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
        echo $tmpName;

```
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );

    is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] ) or error( 'not an HTTP upload' ); 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path ) )
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ) . " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file -->" . $path;
    }

    /*$url="http://rapliq.lerb.polymtl.ca/Symfony/web/app.php/upimg/" . $fileName . "/" . $path . "/";

    $myvars = '';
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $upImgResponse = curl_exec( $ch );*/
} ?>`
```

this problem was with the bath you dont have to give the main root. plus make sure the folder is accessible.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve it. I was actually using this method before using the root... because I though an "absolute path" would be better